# I want to use the Json data and get the uuid to use it as a login form

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

json:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Company",
    "lID": 1,
    "uuid": "56cd87e48528e",
  }
]
```

class:

```
public class details
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int lID { get; set; }
    public string uuid { get; set; }

}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

    var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("url");
    details jsonconvert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<details>(json);

    string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonconvert.uuid);

    /* foreach (var item in jsonconvert){

        if (textBox1.Text == s){

            Form2 secondForm = new Form2();
            secondForm.Show();

        }else{

            MessageBox.Show("Company not found.");

        }
    }*/
}
```

This is the result / problem:

> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1+details'
>   because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to
>   deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. `{"name":"value"}`) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. `JsonArrayAttribute` can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
>
> Path '', line 1, position 1.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the downloaded JSON format? Also, please show the `details` class

Comment: oh sorry here it is ;

Comment: public class details
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public int lID { get; set; }
            public string uuid { get; set; }

        }

Comment: Please edit the question and include that info there instead of just putting it in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the JSON you are feeding the deserializer is an array, i.e. is wrapped in `[` and `]` symbols, yet you are trying to deserialize a single instance.

Either change your JSON to denote a single object, or deserialize a `List` with one element, i.e.:

```
List<details> detailsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<details>>(json);

foreach (details dets in detailsList)
{
     Console.WriteLine(dets.uuid);
}
```

Comment: example please  ? :) this is my first time programming in c#

Comment: @discable10 Example for which option? Do you have control of the JSON that is returned from the URL or not?

Comment: yeah here is the json url :http://dev.ibeaconlivinglab.com:1881/companybyuuid?uuid=56cd87e48528e

Comment: @discable10 I'm not sure if that means you're in control of it or not, and by that I mean, can you change it? Anyways, I'll add an example of deserializing to a list.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra comma at the end of your json object. JSON is very strict about how it needs to be made.

You have to remove the comma, so instead of:

`[ { "id": 1, "name": "Company", "lID": 1, "uuid": "56cd87e48528e", } ]`

It should be:

`[ { "id": 1, "name": "Company", "lID": 1, "uuid": "56cd87e48528e" } ]`

See if that fixes it.

Comment: it is a json url not an array

Comment: thats just the example

Answer (score 0):

> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g.
>   {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a
>   type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList)

1. In `details jsonconvert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<details>(json);`
   jsonconvert is not of type List, hence converting json array into an object will fail. So, class 'details' have to implement ICollection or IList etc.
2. [1,2,3] don't have proper json format, I guess. Good practice will be

   {uuid: 11111, data:[1,2,3]}

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change you deserialization method to

```
 details[] jsonconvert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<details[]>(json);
```